# crystal to ssrs report conversion - lay out issues-Grouping into sections & DocumentMap

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

I am trying to convert a crystal report to SSRS report manually. In crystal report, grouping is done as shown in the below screen shot [that has header name as' report header']. 
Group Name-->and some rows below it.

Is it possible to get similar grouping in SSRS reports. From what I see, grouping is done on columns is SSRS. For ex, see second screen shot[without any header name].

Question:1. Is it possible to get similar grouping in SSRS as it is in crystal.
2.In crystal report, on left side preview, if I click on group name particular group is getting selected. Even if that group is on another, that page becomes visible. Is this functionality possible in SSRS.

Please share the information. Im using SSRS 2008.

[image: SSR screen shot]

[image: screenshot of crystal report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get similar grouping in SSRS as it is in crystal.

Yes: not difficult at all. Insert rows for the group headers. One way to do this: when editing the tablix, right click on the subgroup ("Details," for example) in the "Row Groups" portion of the designer window, and select "Add Total -> Before." This gives you the row you want for the group titles. Next delete the columns you want to remove.

> 2.In crystal report, on left side preview, if I click on group name particular group is getting selected. Even if that group is on another, that page becomes visible. Is this functionality possible in SSRS.

Yes, in SSRS this is called the [Document Map.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239329.aspx)

Comment: for 1: In that case, group name comes below table header. isn't it? yet to try 2.

Comment: Yes, group name is below the table header, but you can add additional rows to any group, including the detail group, and create an addition "header" there.